# How do I secure an MP3 url?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, html5-audio

I am making a music website where I stream free music, but I don't want to user download the mp3 file form my serve.

I use laravel v5.4 framework for backnd and anguler v5.5 for frontend and mp3 music player I use html5.

My application work greatly. In UI no body can't find any mp3 url, But

**When I go browser developer tools and Storage inspector -> Local storage I see my full mp3 url there.**

I look at internet can find any soluton where I can hide the mp3 url or secure them where user can't find url or download directly mp3 from the url.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: You can't. If you want people to be able to read a file they will be able to read the file.

Comment: You'll probably have to set up a special media streaming server that sends blob file portions to your media player piece by piece instead of a single whole file. If you inspect the network activity on youtube or vimeo you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Expounding on what JimL said: It's possible to use the Network tab of Chrome developer tools to see the actual mp3 file being requested and played on some sites that prevent you from seeing the file directly. Even the way YouTube sends blobs can be bypassed via several websites and extensions - like keepvid.com or  genyoutube.com - and then downloaded. You can't hide it from determined people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files):

> For files stored using the `s3` or `rackspace` driver, you may create a temporary URL to a given file using the `temporaryUrl` method. This method accepts a path and a DateTime instance specifying when the URL should expire:

```
$url = Storage::temporaryUrl(
    'file1.jpg', now()->addMinutes(5)
);
```

If you don't use one of these services to store files, you need to create temporary URLs manually.

Comment: Question about s3. i Just upload one mp3 there and copy the link then i put in my track url field, i see its not stream its give me log error HTTP load failed with status 403. Load of media resource

Comment: is there any setting that i have to do in application?

Comment: Yes, you need to setup S3 first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#driver-prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

You can secure the tracks by setting up S3's Bucket Policy.

Example:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy10197062190400",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
       {
            "Sid": "Stmt1597062199047",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::My-project/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http:MyDomain/"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can restrict the music to be served only for `MyDomain`.